# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion, conferences

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the Ask Ubuntu community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant Ubuntu conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: +1 for the idea. I'd love to go but I'm no speaker :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm *very* interested in talking about Ask Ubuntu at a conference, and I  would be going to UDS were it not for lack of <s>sponsorship</s> money.

These are some Linux-/Ubuntu related conferences in 2011:

- Ubuntu and Debian

  - [Ubuntu Developer Summit](http://uds.ubuntu.com/) (May 9th-13th 2011, Budapest, Hungary)
  - [DebConf11](http://debconf11.debconf.org/) (July 24th-30th Banja Luka, Bosnia and Herzegovina)
- Linux and Free Software

  - [FOSSCOMM](http://patras.fosscomm.gr/?lang=en) (May 7th–8th, Patras, Greece)
  - [Linux Tag](http://www.linuxtag.org/2011/en.html) (May 11th–14th, Berlin, Germany)
  - [LinuxCon Europe](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/events/linuxcon-europe/cfp) (October 26th-28th, Prague, Czech Republic)
  - [Desktop Summit](https://www.desktopsummit.org/) (August 6th-12th 2011, Berlin, Germany]

Of those, the UDS and DebConf are essential to our community, Linux Tag, as far as I can tell, is very influential to the Linux community at large.

Comment: Linux tag would be a nice one to hit. UDS and Debconf are developer-related working conferences anyway so I don't think there's much bang-for-the-buck there, I go to those anyway.

Comment: `Desktop Summit` in August? How about that?

Comment: UDS is less than a month away -- could you speak / present there? If so go for it and we'll do our part to make it happen!

Comment: As Jorge says, UDS isn't really relevant. Canonical already sponsor the people who ought to be there to go (the relevant people being developers mostly). Also I don't think there are any open speaker slots or calls for papers.

Answer (score 4):

LWN has a [calendar](http://lwn.net/Calendar/) of all these if you want to peruse.

Here's the ones in North America I would target:

- Southeast Linux Fest: http://www.southeastlinuxfest.org/
- Ohio Linux Fest: http://ohiolinux.org/

Normally I would just do a talk at Ohio (I've spoken there in the past) but unfortunately I won't be able to attend this year. I did run into some ServerFault community folks there last year and I remember people talking about it, so it might be a good 2 birds for one stone with the right speaker.

Pity we missed [SCaLE](http://www.socallinuxexpo.org/), that'd be a nice one for next year.